# logback doesn't log anything if at runtime logback.xml is changed with improper syntax

Tags: logback

I have configured logback.xml with following configuration parameters: `debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds"`

Everything works fine till i make changes in logback.xml. If modified logback.xml is proper / valid xml the changes works fine. But if modified logback.xml is invalid or has some syntax errors, logback doesn't print error info and then onwards it doesn't write any logs to the console.

Is this a known bug or is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug, see [LBCLASSIC-265: Logging stops if invalid xml configuration is loaded by scanner](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-265). The fix has been committed, but not release yet.